From two dataframes with related data, fill columns in the first one (occurrences of a value in 2nd) and merge info
I have two dataframes. The first (df1) has names and the second (df2) has names and the car these persons own.
First, I want to fill the first dataframe with a new column with the occurrences of the same name in the second dataframe.
Then, I want to create a new column in df1, where all cars each person owns are listed.

For the first part I tried this but does not assign correct values.
Could you help with both?**
df1 <- data.frame(Name=c('Nick', 'Mary', 'Linus', 'Eva', 'Michael','John'))
                  
df2 <- data.frame(Name=c('Nick', 'John', 'Mary', 'John', 'Paul', 'John'),
                  Car=c('VW', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Opel', 'Opel', 'VW'))

df1$Occurrences_in_df2 <- length(which(df2$Name==df1$Name))


You can do the following:
library(tidyverse)
df1 |>
  left_join(df2 |> 
              reframe(cars_in_df2 = toString(Car),
                      Occurences_in_df2 = n(),
                      .by = Name),
            by = "Name")

     Name     cars_in_df2 Occurences_in_df2
1    Nick              VW                 1
2    Mary          Toyota                 1
3   Linus            <NA>                NA
4     Eva            <NA>                NA
5 Michael            <NA>                NA
6    John Volvo, Opel, VW                 3

You need two parts here:

inner part: within your df, you want to summarize/reframe your data so that it counts the occurences of Names as well as combines the car brands into one single value.
outer part: you then want to merge this info with your df1 by Name

I didn't tidy up the results further so that you can see what's the true result of it. Replacing the NAs by zero shouldn't be too difficult.

With base R you can try aggregate + merge like below
transform(
  aggregate(Car ~ ., merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), c, na.action = na.pass),
  OccurInDf2 = lengths(Car) * !is.na(Car)
)

which gives
     Name             Car OccurInDf2
1     Eva              NA          0
2    John Volvo, Opel, VW          3
3   Linus              NA          0
4    Mary          Toyota          1
5 Michael              NA          0
6    Nick              VW          1


Aggregate then merge:
merge(df1, 
      aggregate(df2, Car ~ Name, FUN = function(x) c(brands = toString(x), n = length(x))),
      by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)
#     Name      Car.brands Car.n
#1     Eva            <NA>  <NA>
#2    John Volvo, Opel, VW     3
#3   Linus            <NA>  <NA>
#4    Mary          Toyota     1
#5 Michael            <NA>  <NA>
#6    Nick              VW     1


data.table
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

df1 <- data.frame(Name=c('Nick', 'Mary', 'Linus', 'Eva', 'Michael','John'))

df2 <- data.frame(Name=c('Nick', 'John', 'Mary', 'John', 'Paul', 'John'),
                  Car=c('VW', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Opel', 'Opel', 'VW'))

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[, list(Car = toString(unique(Car)), OccurInDf2 = length(unique(Car))), by = Name] %>% 
  .[df1, on = list(Name)]
#>       Name             Car OccurInDf2
#> 1:    Nick              VW          1
#> 2:    Mary          Toyota          1
#> 3:   Linus            <NA>         NA
#> 4:     Eva            <NA>         NA
#> 5: Michael            <NA>         NA
#> 6:    John Volvo, Opel, VW          3

Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.0.2
